# Linux/Ubuntu: Cannot make panel elements be level parent

Tags: linux, firefox-addon

The default setting for panels in linux is to be level of parent.

I added this code to test:

```
function onpanelshowing(e) {
  e.target.setAttribute('level', 'parent');
}

window.addEventListener('popupshowing', onpanelshowing, true);
window.addEventListener('popuphiding', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

If you run this code from scratchpad, we see that all panels are opened and never closed. Now if you press Alt + Tab you will see that alt+tab menu is underneath these panel elements. Is there anyway to get panels in linux to behave as level of parent?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/panel#a-panel.level

Comment: I filed a bug for you, as I also could not figure this one out, the code i used to test is in the bugzilla topic, I also tested on mac and your situation holds true: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1180490